# Why does the Service information disappear on ArcGIS Server Manager?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1

I have 41 services on our ArcGIS Server. The Server Manager holds roughly 10/page. When I click on any page other than page 1, the service information disappears (status, number of instances, etc.)

[image]

When I refresh, it always takes me back to page 1. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Running ArcGIS Server 10.1

The services disappear in IE 9 and Firefox. I can't login via Chrome so no way of telling if it would work or not.

Comment: Can you bump the number of services per page to maximum? (50, I believe) Also, I've had random trouble with Server Manager in Chrome recently, so I switched to Firefox.

Comment: I also cannot get in with Chrome. Just bumped it to 50 and now I don't get service info for any services.

Comment: Set your logging to "Verbose" or even "Debug" for a few minutes and see if any errors are getting reported. I've had missing info from services before and it was because I messed up deploying a GP tool.

Comment: look at your compatibility mode and add the url to trusted sites in ie. The chrome problem I think esri knows about.

Comment: I also cannot log in via chrome. The page just never loads! Mozilla it is!

Comment: Which browser and version are you using?  This would be a useful detail to edit into your Question.